# Detecting an embedded Tweet that's been deleted

Tags: javascript, twitter, embed, tweets

If you embed a Tweet on your web page and the Tweet's author subsequently deletes the original, the embed will continue to display on your web page, albeit minus the author's avatar and the intent links.

I would like to hide such Tweets, or possibly send a call to my server to delete these objects in my database. I assume that the author had a reason for deleting and would probably prefer that the Tweet no longer be displayed.

I'm not a JavaScript pro, so I'm just guessing that there's something in http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js that detects this condition, so that the avatar and links are not shown.

Can I capture this and use it to hide the embed or make an ajax call?

I already have jQuery on the page, if that helps.

[edit] Another thing: 'live' embedded Tweets include a

```
    <span class=avatar>
```

containing an image. That same span is empty if the Tweet has been deleted. Can this be detected with JavaScript?

Comment: What widget.js? I'm missing on some context. What made you guess?

Comment: Sorry. platform.twitter.com/widgets.js needs to be present on the page in order for embedded tweets to display correctly. It's way too hard for me to understand, but it knows how to display 'live' tweets differently from deleted ones. I'm also editing my question to add something new that might make this easier.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but I had a similar problem and I found a solution.

The way I worked around it was to use a css rule applied to the blockquotes inside the oembed. If you do something like this:

```
.container blockquote {
    display: none;
}
```

Basically the widgets.js javascript will automatically remove this css rule but only for tweets that exist, leaving the ones that don't exist as display:none, and hidden.

This seems a little hacky but until twitter provides us with a slightly nicer javascript api for widgets it seems like an ok solution.

Answer (score 0):

If the Tweet has been deleted, the blockquote element stays and the iframe comes with a height of 0. I load the embedded Tweets via jQuery ajax and the widget.js with $.getScript().

```
jQuery.getScript('http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js', function() {
    $('blockquote.twitter-tweet').remove();
});
```